# ld_library_path does not work in makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

The makefile has the following commands:

```
exrtl:
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:libs

clean:
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=""
```

But nothing happens after them. If you then enter

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then nothing will change. You have to enter it manually. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "if you then enter ...".  You mean, you run `make` then at the same command prompt you run the `echo`?  That can't work.  It's a fundamental tenet of all (POSIX) systems that a process cannot change the environment of its parent process.  `make` is no exception to this absolute rule.